# Generating subclass models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, model-view-controller, model

If for example I have a superclass model: Food, and some subclass models: Cake, Vegetables, Pasta, Cheese, who inherit some attributes from Food as well as having their own attributes, how would arrange this in rails? And how would it work in the db schema?
Would I generate the superclass model first, and are there then some tricks to generating the subclass models already as subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating sub-classes tables in db then it looks case of `association`, like `Cake belongs_to Food` and `Food has_many Cake` But if you have only one table called Food in db then it is the case of [Single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance)